# Efeito na borda de um componente JButton

Tags: java, swing

Como faço para criar uma transição(Efeito fade) suave da borda de um JButton, ao passar o mouse?

Meu código está assim:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    Object temp = e.getSource();
    if (temp instanceof JButton)
        ((JButton)temp).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 1, false);
    /* restante do código */
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    Object temp = e.getSource();
    if (temp instanceof JButton)
       ((JButton)temp).setBorder(null);
    /* restante do código */
}
```

Como consigo esse tipo de resultado? Procurei em alguns fóruns e artigos, mas nada que tratasse esse detalhe.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que procura algo neste sentido:

[image: botão e botão com o mouse sobre]

```
package br;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CriarJButton extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CriarJButton() {
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        final botaoFade bt = new botaoFade("StackOverflow.pt");
        bt.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
               bt.setAlpha((float)0.6);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                bt.setAlpha((float)1);
            }
        });
        add(bt);

    }

    private static void cria_MostraInterface() {

        JFrame painel = new CriarJButton();
        painel.pack();
        painel.setVisible(true);
        painel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                cria_MostraInterface();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class botaoFade extends JButton {

        private static final JButton lafDeterminer = new JButton();
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private boolean rectangularLAF;
        private float alpha = 1f;

        botaoFade() {
            this(null, null);
        }

        botaoFade(String texto) {
            this(texto, null);
        }

        botaoFade(String texto, Icon icon) {
            super(texto, icon);
            setOpaque(false);
            setFocusPainted(false);
        }

        public float getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
            java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
            if (rectangularLAF && isBackgroundSet()) {
                Color c = getBackground();
                g2.setColor(c);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
            super.paintComponent(g2);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateUI() {
            super.updateUI();
            lafDeterminer.updateUI();
            rectangularLAF = lafDeterminer.isOpaque();
        }
    }
}
```

Eu optei por modificar o botão todo, mas se quiser aplicar só na borda, não será tão difícil.

Se quiser, pode baixar o código no [gist](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/a14336ce15105cdc01f1).

Comment: Eu rodei o seu código e não entendi exatamente para que ele serve. Se eu quiser por exemplo aumentar o tempo de transição (fade), é possível?

Comment: Estou com a mesma dúvida postada pelo Math.